# How to use keydown event with getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom, onkeydown

how to use keydown event if i change getElementById to getElementByTagName

snipping code from w3school

```
<script>
function keydownFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function keyupFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
</script>
```

I changed to

```
<p>
<input type="text" id="demo" onkeydown="keydownFunction()" onkeyup="keyupFunction()">
</p>

<script>
function keydownFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("p").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function keyupFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("p").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
</script>
```

and it doesnt work

Comment: There's no `getElementByTagName` but there is `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: sorry it was a typo and it's still the same

Comment: ```document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";``` Try this

Comment: var all_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(let e of all_tag){
  e.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}